# Pass WebView from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have some problem with passing a WebView from the first activity to the second activity. I have tried `putExtra` and so on, but it complains that I'm trying to pass a WebView instead of a String.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WebView.class);
intent.putExtra("myPassedWebView", mWebView);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never pass widgets between activities. You will create memory leaks. Please find another solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Well, the problem itself is that I have my WebView inside a TabLayout, and I want to free my WebView from the TabLayout. Otherwise, my tabs gonna be at the top even if my WebView is open. Therefore I tried to solve it this way.

Comment: @Julian Assange: Get rid of the tabs, then. You need to design your UI such that the `WebView` resides in a single activity.

Comment: Well, the tabs are needed for the rest of the application, and the WebView appears from one of my earlier views from my TabLayout.

Comment: just get the info you need from the webview and make a new one?

Comment: @Julian Assange: Then leave the `WebView` in the tab. Or, as schwiz suggests, get the URL from the current `WebView`, pass that in the `Intent` extras, and load up the URL again (I think you may wind up with the same cookies -- not sure about that). You cannot have the same `WebView` in multiple activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare: So instead of the new activity, I pass the cookie values into the Extras and then create my webview in the new activity instead of passing it?

Comment: @Julian Assange: I think so. It is a bit difficult to piece together your app from various questions and comments scattered about SO, so I can't be certain that's the right pattern for you, but it sounds plausible.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you once again, and the solution sounds right. :)

Answer (score 2):

Very old topic but I had the same problem.

Not sure if this is a correct way to do it. But I solved the problem by creating a singleton class where I store the webview I use.

When I launch the new activity where I need the same webview I remove it from the parentLayout and add it again in the new activityLayout in `onCreate();`

There won't be memoryleaks since putExtra method is not used and you will only have one instance of the webview.

Create webview and store it in singletonclass:

```
Singleton.getInstance().setWebView((WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainwebview));
```

Remove the webview from parentLayout before you start activity:

```
((ViewGroup)Singleton.getInstance().getWebView().getParent()).removeView(Singleton.getInstance().getWebView());

Intent i = new Intent(getApplication().getBaseContext(), WebActivity.class);

startActivity(i);
```

in new activity onCreate() add webview in the new layout:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.webActivity)).addView(Singleton.getInstance().getWebView());
```

Then you can pass the webview between your activities the way you want.

Comment: How can we deal with situation after onBackPressed is called. It will throw NullPointerException